Parametric Region with Interpolating Function
How can I create a ParametricRegion from InterpolatingFunctions?
Let's say we have:
points1 = 
  Table[2  {Cos[k  2  Pi/8], Sin[k  2  Pi/16]}, {k, 0., 15, 0.1}];
    s1 = Rescale[
       Flatten[N[
         Accumulate[
          Join[{{0}}, 
           Map[Sqrt[# . #] &, Rest[points1] - Most[points1]]]]]]];
    x1 = Interpolation[MapThread[{#1, #2[[1]]} &, {s1, points1}], 
       Method -> "Spline"];
    y1 = Interpolation[MapThread[{#1, #2[[2]]} &, {s1, points1}], 
       Method -> "Spline"];

Now, ParametricPlot works on this:
ParametricPlot[{x1[s], y1[s]}, {s, 0, 1}]


Also, from the first example of ParametricRegion, we can see:
ParametricPlot[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2  Pi}]
Region@ParametricRegion[{Cos[t], Sin[t]}, {{t, 0, 2  Pi}}]

results in:

But with similar syntax:
Region@ParametricRegion[{x1[s], y1[s]}, {{s, 0, 1}}] 

Doesn't work:

Using Evaluate didn't help either.
One of the comments point out that RegionPlot works on this. But I wanted to use it with other functions for Regions for example:
region1 = ParametricRegion[{x1[s], y1[s]}, {{s, 0, 1}}];
RegionNearest[region1, {0., 1.}]

doesn't work either.

It works perfectly fine, you get back a Region object. You can also plot it if you want RegionPlot@Region@ParametricRegion[{x1[s], y1[s]}, {{s, 0, 1}}].

Interesting, so it seems like the Region when called with the circle example automatically plots, but not with this.

Please see the update, there is still something wrong with the region.

For performing further calculations, you will likely have to discretize your region, for example: DiscretizeRegion[region1, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}].

Thanks, that does seem to work!  It initially gave errors and needed the bounds again: DiscretizeRegion[region1, {0, 1}, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> 0.1}] works.

It means that Region can not automatic discretize such region.
